# url rewrite using .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have three urls

http://thewebby.net16.net/Welcome.php

http://thewebby.net16.net/AboutMe.php

http://thewebby.net16.net/Projects.php

How to rewrite these urls to

http://thewebby.net16.net/The-Webby-home/

http://thewebby.net16.net/Aboute-Me/

http://thewebby.net16.net/Check-out-my-portfolio-and-projects/

```
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex Welcome.php

RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^The-Webby-home/?$    Welcome.php   [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "TheWebby"/Aboute-Me/
RewriteRule    ^About-Me/?$    AboutMe.php   [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "TheWebby"
```

I was hosting in a free domain so error page was not showing it gets redirected to error page provided by the hosting provider .When I tried with

http://localhost/TheWebby/About-Me/  **it redirects to AboutMe.php successfully but when I try to navigate to welcome.php it 
the url changes to**

http://localhost/TheWebby/About-Me/The-Webby-home/

**instead of**

http://localhost/TheWebby/The-Webby-home/

Comment: And *how* is it not working? Error logs, sample URL and result etc? Also make up your mind about 90s-style mixed-case filenames. It's unlikely that the directoryindex `Welcome.php` works when the rewriterule uses a lowercase `welcome.php`.

Comment: its not working I want The-Webby-home/ for welcome.php to appear for seo optimization but instead Welcome.php is appearing

Comment: That's not what RewriteRules do. They're just for remapping *incoming* URLs, not fixing existing links and HTML. See "ping-pong rewrites".

Comment: @ mario if incoming url /The-Webby-home/ is incoming  it redirects to Welcome.php ?

Comment: @mario can you help out on this specific issue

Comment: Bro I have updated the question please check it